# write.table with sep="\t" not displaying in-line

Tags: r, file, write.table

I have used a write.table function to write 100 matrices into individual files where I have clearly specified that the matrix values need to be separated by "\t".

```
     for(i in 1:length(listofmatrices1)){
       write.table(listofmatrices1[[i]], file=(paste("traj1", as.character(i), ".txt", sep="")), row.names=FALSE, sep="\t")
     }
```

However, the files do not appear that way... and every digit with only 3 decimals is out of place.

```
     "X"    "Y"
     164.8034   164.8034
     164.8546   164.8546
     164.831 164.831
     164.8784   164.8784
     165.4194   165.4194
     166.5505   166.5505
     166.652 166.652
     167.0379    167.0379
```

I think that this is perturbing downstream analyses that I'm doing where I'm trying to iterate through the files' contents. How does this happen and how to stop it?

Comment: I think that's just because of how it is displayed. Tabs are typically 8 chars wide (but I suspect they are 4 here), and the 3-decimal numbers are 7 chars wide (`164.831`), it only takes 1 more char to align to the next tab stop. With `164.1234` the string is 8 chars wide and so 4 (or 8) chars will be inserted to align with the next tab stop.

Comment: Also, what is the down the line error which you think is being created here?

Comment: oh ok thanks do you know why I would get the following error when iterating through the files:Error in table[, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions
using the following command:
ComputeStepSize<-function(table){
  deltastepY <- diff(table[,2][seq(1,length(table[,2]), 2)])
  deltastepX <- diff(table[,1][seq(1,length(table[,2]), 2)])
  overalldelta<-sqrt(deltastepY**2+deltastepX**2)
  return(overalldelta)
}

Answer (score 0):

While the files might not look in line, change out that "\t" for a "," and you will see that there is a separator there.  If you open the file with an open spreadsheet reader, like LibreOffice or OpenOffice, then you will see the numbers line up into columns.

Comment: oh ok thanks do you know why I would get the following error when iterating through the files:Error in table[, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions
using the following command:
ComputeStepSize<-function(table){
  deltastepY <- diff(table[,2][seq(1,length(table[,2]), 2)])
  deltastepX <- diff(table[,1][seq(1,length(table[,2]), 2)])
  overalldelta<-sqrt(deltastepY**2+deltastepX**2)
  return(overalldelta)
}

Comment: the formatting of chat collapses your code, it is hard to read.  Can you open a new question or edit your existing question to include this code?